# Join two lists of different objects and create a new list

Tags: c#, list, linq

I've got two lists of different objects.

```
List<ObjA> objAs = new List<ObjA>();
List<ObjB> objBs = new List<ObjB>();
```

They have the following class structures.

```
public class ObjA
{
    public int Id;
    public int ObjBId;
}

public class ObjB
{
    public int Id;
    public string Title;
}
```

Joining objA's `ObjBId` property to ObjB's `Id` property, I want to create a list of ObjA's Ids alongside ObjB's Titles. Something like this:

```
List<int, string> output = new List<int, string>();
// where int = ObjA's Id, string = ObjB's Title
```

How can I do this in LINQ? Are there any alternative than using Concat and creating a wrapper class?

Comment: What happens to the A's who refer to a non-existing B, or Bs who aren't being referred to by an A? Are you expecting them to be omitted from the final result?

Comment: Yes, I want them to be omitted.

Answer (score 4):

You can use [`Join`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.join?view=netcore-3.1) method and return a result as list of named tuples `List<(int, string)>` (available beginning with C# 7), becuase `List<int, string>` isn't a valid C# declaration.

```cs
var output = objAs.Join(objBs, a => a.ObjBId, b => b.Id, (a, b) => (a.Id, b.Title)).ToList();
```

You may also use anonymous objects instead of tuples, e.g. `(a, b) => new { a.Id, b.Title}`

Comment: @Bhav does it answer your question, do you need more details?

Answer (score 2):

[`Enumerable.Join`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.join) should help you in this.

```
var result = objAs.Join(objBs,x=>x.ObjBId,y=>y.Id,(x,y)=>new {x.Id,y.Title})
                  .ToList();
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use a join and return a list

```
var result = (from a in objAs
    join b in objBs on a.ObjBId equals b.Id
    select new
    {
       a.ObjBId,
       b.Title
    }).ToList();
```

Answer (score 0):

So for every element of objAs, you want to take the Id, and if an object with the same Id is in objBs, you want the Id from objA and the title from objB.

In fact, since the Id of objA and objB are equal, you don't care if you take the Id from objA or from objB.

You didn't write what you want if there is no item in objBs with the same Id.
Let's assume you want null in that case.

```
var result = objAs.GroupJoin(objBs,  // GroupJoin A with B
    objA => objA.Id,                 // from every element in A take the Id
    objB => objB.Id,                 // from every element in B take the Id

    // ResultSelector: take all elements of A, each with the matching elements from B
    (objA, matchingObjBs) => new
    {
        Id = objA.Id,
        Title = matchingObjBs.Select(objB => objB.Title).FirstOrDefault(),
    });
```

The nice thing about GroupJoin, is that you also get the element from A that have no matching B. And if there are more than one matching item in B, you take the first one.

If you don't want the items from A that have no matching Id in B, it is enough to take only the elements from B that have an Id in A:

```
var idsA = objAs.Select(objA => objA.Id);
var result = objBs.Where(objB => idsA.Contains(objB.Id));
```